# What should a room in a hospital where nurses dress wounds of patients be called?

Tags: word-request, american-english, british-english

[Bing's dictionary](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=dressing%20definition&setmkt=en-US&PC=EMMX01&form=LWT001&scope=web) (which in turn is based on some Oxford dictionary) says that verb dress has this sense:

> clean, treat, or apply a dressing to (a wound): "she washed the wound
> and dressed it with fresh bandages"

What should a room in a hospital where nurses dress wounds of patients be called?

Is it called dressing room, as in this photo which a blogger took in a hospital in China, and as in Pakistan https://lifecarefoundationtrust.org/dressing-room/? Does dressing room mean a room for changing clothes in America? What do Americans call a dressing room in a hospital?

[image]

Comment: A dressing room can be a room in a hospital or clinic used for dressing wounds, or a room where people may dress or change clothes. Context will make clear which meaning is applicable. This is true in all parts of the English speaking world.

Comment: In UK in this context it means "room for dressing wounds". Otherwise it would be called a "changing room" in a sports hall, swimming pool, etc.

Comment: ... a dressing room can also be found in a theatre, that is, for hospital operating theatre surgeons or for performance theatre artists. Neither of those will have a public notice directing people there.

Comment: If it's a general purpose room where various other medical procedures also take place then it would probably be called a "treatment room". I once broke my arm and the hospital had a special room reserved for applying casts. They called the "plaster room" presumably because it can be a messy job.

Comment: It *could* even mean the location in a factory where oil, spices and vinegar are mixed... or not ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)A room in a hospital that is dedicated to a particular class is called a "ward".  Hospitals that I have been in (fortunately not many) don't have dedicated rooms for dressing wounds.  Dressing a wound would be part of emergency care in an "Accident and Emergency (or A&E) Department", or (in smaller hospitals) A "Minor Injury Unit" or "Urgent Treatment Centre". There may also be a "Trama Ward" in larger hospitals to which patients are admitted if their injuries are too severe to be treated in A&E.

Wounds would also need to be dressed following surgery, but these would be dressed in the operating theatre.

I've tagged "British English" as hospital terminology tends to be different in different countries, eg in the USA A&E is called an "Emergency Room" or ER.

Generally "dressing room" would be understood to mean "room for getting dressed" (for example in a theatre), though the context of the hospital might make it more ambiguous.

Comment: of the other parts of that sign, I would not know what a "register" was for, and of course most UK hospitals don't have a "cashier".  "Dispensary" and "Emergency Room" would probably not be the BrE words, and UK hospitals don't have a "general consulting room".  As you don't go to hospital to talk but to receive treatment. The initial contact with a doctor is made with a GP or in A&E.

Comment: A ward is particularly a room or set of rooms where patients stay in bed for days or longer; often used for rooms with multiple beds, or collections of closely-connected rooms supervised by the same nurse(s). Traditionally it was one large room with lots of beds, but today it's also used in some hospitals for a group of individual rooms. A room where people go for short treatments, for minor surgery, or to consult a doctor would not be a ward.